# Looking for number around

Tags: c#

Hey i would like faster way for looking number around, let me explain:

```
int[] num = { 55, 155};

if (funcNum == num[0],funcNum == num[0]+1,funcNum == num[0]+2,funcNum == num[0]+3,funcNum == num[1]-1,funcNum == num[1]-2,funcNum == num[1]-3)
```

// dostuff

so basically i would like fast method to know if someNumber is equal to num(+x to -x) like num is 55 and i want to know if its equal to numbers from 40 to 70 counting 55 too

thanks!

Comment: What if `funcNum == num[1]`? Or `funcNum == num[1] + 1`?

Comment: Will `Math.Abs(funcNum - num[0]) <= x` do the job?

Comment: `if (a>40 && a <70)` ?

Comment: @rbm faster way doesnt exist?

Comment: @yoloscope what do you mean "a faster way"?

Comment: @yoloscope Do you mean faster to execute or faster to write?

Comment: if (A && B) is pretty fast - it's just comparing numbers, computer is pretty good at it. No need to call another function that'd take some more CPU cycles...

Comment: faster to write aka more clean

Comment: in which case `if(A && B)` is the cleanest and does not scare people with Math.Abs ;)

Comment: Please revise your question to indicate you want a "cleaner" or "more readable" method or writing this then. "faster" would indicate that you want it to execute faster.

Comment: @rbm, if you include your result as an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for premature optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
int range = 5; // your range here
if ((funcNum <= num[0] + range) && (funcNum >= num[0] - range)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you wanted to test with all numbers in your array, you could do:

```
int range = 5; // your range here
bool inRange = true;
if (!num.Any(i => funcNum <= i + range && funcNum >= i - range))
{
    inRange = false;
}    

if (inRange)
{
    // do something
}
```

(here's hoping that I've understood your question correctly)

EDIT: Modified so that `inRange` is `true` when `funcNum` is in any of the ranges, not all of them.

Comment: The test for num[1] is missing. Maybe there are some more values than two in `num`.

Comment: That second part can be simplified by using `Any`.  `if(num.Any(i => funcNum <= i + range && funcNum >= i - range))`. Right now you answer is more of an `All` where it's still true if `num` is empty, which isn't likely to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, my mistake - I assumed that `funcNum` had to be in the range of all of the numbers in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are asking?:

```
if (( someNumber <= num[0] + x ) && ( someNumber >= num[0] - x)){
    //someNumber is within range
}
else{
    //someNumber is not within range
}
```

Check out equality signs like >, <, >= and <=, it will help you perform your checks faster.

If your num[0] is 55, your x is 15, that means num[0]+x is 70, and num[0]-x is 40, and if someNumber is less than or equal to 70, and (&&) someNumber is greater than or equal to 40, then the check returns true.

Comment: This condition true for all `x >= 0`. There is no test for another value. I think the condition should be `funcNum <= num[0] + x && funcNum >= num[0] - x`

Comment: Yes Vera rind thanks for helping me see what the question is asking.

Comment: There's another problem: This condition doesn't test for `num[1]`. The sample code does (only in negative direction - maybe a mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ranges don't overlap (some methods below can tolerate multiple ranges like dictionary approach can have lists of ranges for each number)

- If you have small range of possible numbers that you can simply trade memory for speed and have map of all numbers to particular range - O(1):

  {3, 9} with tolerance 1 (so expecting 2,3,4 to map to 3, and 8,9,10 to 9)

  ```
   var map = new Dictionary<int,int> ({2,3}, {3,3},{4,3}, {8,9}, {9,9, 10,9}};
   if (map.ContainsKey(funcNum)) ....
  ```

Note that if you don't need to know exact range some sort of bitmap/`HasSet` can be used to decrease memory requirements.

- If there are a lot of numbers - sort the list and find possible range with binary search (O(log number_of_ranges)).
- If number of ranges is small (measure, but I guess 3-5 would be the target) than regular loop and check if number is next to current (as shown in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32567619/477420)) should work fine (O(number_of_ranges)).

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments above: `if (a>40 && a<70)` is the fastest (and cleanest from code point of view).

It is a simple operation which does not require a call to another function (i.e. you'd not be using more CPU cycles).